# Any downside to pre making marinade and then putting it in the fridge?

Tags: grilling, marinade

I was just wondering, is there any downside to making a marinade and then storing it in the fridge before it's used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, for most marinades, there should be no reason you cannot make them in advance and refrigerate.  It may even allow some improvements as flavors from any herbs or spices infuse into the liquid.

You just want to practice good food safety, which means putting it in the refrigerator as soon as it is made.